# How to synchronise a foreign table with a local table?

Tags: postgresql, oracle-fdw

I'm using the Oracle foreign data wrapper and would like to have local copies of some of my foreign tables locally. Is there another option than having materialized views and refreshing them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, unless you want to add functionality in Oracle:

- If you add a trigger on the Oracle table that records all data modifications in another table, you could define a foreign table on that table. Then you can regularly run a function in PostgreSQL that takes the changes since you checked last time and applies them to a PostgreSQL table.
- If you understand how “materialized view logs” work in Oracle (I don't, and I think the documentation doesn't tell), you could define a foreign table on that and use it like above. That might be cheaper.

Both of these ideas would still require you to regularly run something in PostgreSQL, but you might be cheaper. Perhaps (if you have the money) you could use Oracle Heterogenous Services to modify a PostgreSQL table whenever something changes in an Oracle table.